# How to check if array of object's properties are empty or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to check the following array have any empty value or not

Example

The following should return `true`

```js
[
    {
        "price": "12",
        "number": "1"
    },
    {
        "price": "12",
        "number": "1"
    }
]
```

The following should return `false`

```js
[
    {
        "price": "12",
        "number": "1"
    },
    {
        "price": "12",
        "number": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: No. Because it has both keys and values, but the other doesn't have one value.

Comment: Shouldn't the first example be false, and the second example be true, if the question is "Does it have an empty value or not"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to check whether one of the property value's length of an item in the array is smaller than `1`:

```js
const arr=[{price:"12",number:"1"},{price:"12",number:"1"}];

const isValid = !arr.some(e => Object.values(e).some(f => f.length < 1))

console.log(isValid)
```

Comment: Why `f.length < 1` instead of `f.length == 0` ?

Comment: Just a side note: a problem might arise if the `number` attribute can contain an actual number, or be `null` or `undefined` rather than an empty string; in that case `f.length` would throw an error. If values other than strings should be taken into account, it might be worth replacing `f => f.length < 1` with `f => ['', null, undefined].includes(f)`

Comment: @BenkI + at *secan* ... For exactly such edge cases it was always better if the OP would specify the exact requirements. Otherwise the OP gets A's which exactly match/cover what was ask for. Also, how are empty items ...  `{ }` ... (no properties no values) supposed to be handled?

Comment: @PeterSeliger just to be clear, I was not implying the answer given by Spectric is wrong or incomplete; I just thought it could be worth mentioning the issue in case the OP did not take that eventuality into consideration.

Comment: @secan ... Me neither, that's the reason for having primarily addressed the OP in my above comment.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function isNonEmptyValue(value) {
  return (
    (value != null)
    && (value !== '') 
  //&& any other *empty* value constraint
  );
}
function hasEntriesAndNoEmptyValues(item) {
  const values = Object.values(item);
  return (
    values.length >= 1 &&
    values.every(value => isNonEmptyValue(value))
  );
}

console.log(
  [{
    "price": "12",
    "number": "1",
  }, {
    "price": "12",
    "number": "",

  }].every(hasEntriesAndNoEmptyValues)
);
console.log(
  [{
    "price": "12",
    "number": "1",
  }, {
    "price": "12",
    "number": " ",

  }].every(hasEntriesAndNoEmptyValues)
);
console.log(
  [{

  }, {
    "price": "12",
    "number": " ",

  }].every(hasEntriesAndNoEmptyValues)
);
```